# How do I update HTML content

Tags: updating

We have a website that is linked to a drupal database. I need to update some HTML text and could not find the file on our server but did find the content in two tables in the drupal DB: dbo.field_data_body and dbo.filed_revision.

I made the change in the db but this has not been relayed to the site.

Please advise

Thank you,
Kai

Comment: First you should use Drupal API to handle content. It is not a good idea to just update straight via SQL query. Why not use the Drupal node edit interface for that?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have admin access to drupal API but have access to the DB and IIS. I assumed that the content from these tables would export into an editable markup file but this does not appear to be the case. Can i do this without the drupal API?

Kai